# Как в Matplotlib сделать цикл для автоматического построения графиков с заявленными параметрами

Tags: python, dataframe, графика, matplotlib

Есть функция

```
def super_show_spb(data, index, values, locality_name, columns=None, aggfunc="count",
               fill_value=0, dropna=True, figsize=(12, 5), grid=True, **kwargs):
    (city_center_data
     .query('locality_name == locality_name')
     .pivot_table(index=index, values=values, columns=columns,
                  aggfunc=aggfunc, fill_value=fill_value, dropna=dropna)
     .plot.bar(figsize=figsize, grid=grid, **kwargs))
super_show_spb(data= city_center_data, index='year', values='last_price', locality_name = '"Санкт-Петербург" and cityCenters_nearest_km == 3')
```

**как можно сделать тоже самое через цикл**

```
for columns in city_center_data(['year', 'month', 'weekday']):
    (city_center_data.query('locality_name == "Санкт-Петербург" and cityCenters_nearest_km == 3')
    .pivot_table(index=column, values= 'last_price', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
    .plot.bar(figsize=(12, 5), grid=True))
    plt.show()
```

попробовал в формате

```
for columns in city_centre_data:
    columns = (['year', 'month', 'weekday'])
    (city_center_data.query('locality_name == "Санкт-Петербург" and cityCenters_nearest_km == 3')
    .pivot_table(index=columns, values= 'last_price', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
    .plot.bar(figsize=(12, 5), grid=True))
    plt.show()
```

но выходят все данные на одном графике
В итоге должно получиться три разных графика для столбцов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы рисуете три графика на одном и том же `axes`. для того, чтобы у вас получилось три отдельных графика, нужно менять `axes`. Например так:

```
fig = plt.figure()
total_axes = len(df.columns) # общее количество графиков (в данном случае
                             # берем равным количеству колонок в датафрейме
subplt = 1 # номер начального axes
for x in df.columns:
    ax = fig.add_subplot(total_axes, 1, subplt) # добавляем axes для каждого графика
    df[x].plot() #отрисовываем график
    subplt+=1

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У меня еще вышел вот такой вариант

```
for columns in ['year', 'month', 'weekday']:
    (city_center_data.query('locality_name == "Санкт-Петербург" and cityCenters_nearest_km == 3')
    .pivot_table(index=columns, values= 'last_price', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
    .plot.bar(figsize=(12, 5), grid=True))
    plt.show()
```